# WebAPI escape serialized json array

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

When the response is 200 it returns the result correctly. However, when it's a bad request it can not return the result as deserialized json because the responseString actually has a JSON array. So I considered skipping the desalinization step when it's a bad request. However, now I get the result but with escaped quotes i.e.  {\"property\":\"value\"} and I could figure out a way t return the bad request as JSON but without the the escaped char.

here is my code:

```
public async Task<TResponse> PostAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(Uri uri, TRequest request)
        {
            var jsonContent = (request as object).SerializeAsCamelCaseJson();

            var requestString = await jsonContent.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            Logger.Debug(requestString);

            var result = await this.httpClient.PostAsync(uri, jsonContent).TimeoutAfter(this.Timeout).ConfigureAwait(false);

            TResponse response;
            string responseString;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                responseString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().TimeoutAfter(this.Timeout).ConfigureAwait(false);

                response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(responseString);


                return response;
            }

            responseString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().TimeoutAfter(this.Timeout).ConfigureAwait(false);
            throw new Exception(responseString);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the responseString has escaped quotes or is it just Visual Studio that is doing that?  ReasAsStringAsync doesn't escape anything from what I have seen.  Try doing JToken.Parse(responseSring) and see if it parses correctly.

Comment: yes this what I get when I consume the api :
{
  "message": "[{\"errorCode\":\"ERROR_HERE\",\"errorDescription\":\"DESCRIPTION_HERE\"},{\"errorCode\":\"INVALID_PAYLOAD\",\"errorDescription\":\"Field info abbout the error \"},{\"errorCode\":\"INVALID_PAYLOAD\",\"errorDescription\":\"Field captureSystemId is invalid\"}]\n[{\"errorCode\":\"DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION\",\"errorDescription\":\"Transaction already exists\"}

Comment: But where do you get that?  Did you try parsing it using JToken.Parse?

Comment: Are you writing the server API too?  Can you show your server code?